# VirtualHost 500 error (Apache 2.4.10 / Debian)

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Good Morning StackOverFlow.. I have been troubleshooting this for quite a while.

Problem: When I try to access http://newdash.new it returns a 500 error. This happens both when accessing the URL locally and over the LAN.

Running on Debian8 with Apache 2.4.10
Below is my

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/newdash.conf
```

Here:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName newdash.new

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "/var/www/newdash/public"


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/newdash/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Nov 13 10:51 newdash
```

I can ping the named route (newdash.new) both locally and over the LAN and the ip resolves properly.

In my Apache2 error log:

```
[Fri Nov 13 11:45:51.345101 2015] [:error] [pid 1958] [client 10.1.1.108:56899] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/newdash/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/newdash/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/newdash/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /var/www/newdash/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289):
```

So it appears there is a permissions error on that directory..

I don't know what other information would be helpful...

Thank you.

Comment: First thing you should _always_ to when configuring an http server: look into the http servers error log file if something does not work as expected. What does it say in there?

Comment: Apart from that: under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` should be kept symlinks only, the configurations belong to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in the error log.

```
[Fri Nov 13 11:45:51.345101 2015] [:error] [pid 1958] [client 10.1.1.108:56899] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/newdash/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/newdash/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/newdash/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /var/www/newdash/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289):
```

As suggested, after looking there, I realized the permissions on the /storage/logs/ folder was causing the issues.

Thank you for the suggestion arkascha!